# Why running .bat file thru Task Scheduler is not starting the .Jar file fully?

Tags: batch-file, jar, scheduled-tasks, javaw

Here is what is going on. I have created a .Bat file containing `start javaw -jar BTG_Producer.jar` When I start this manually by double clicking it will show my java program in my system tray and shows the process "javaw.exe *32" in Windows Task Manager. When I run this thru Task Scheduler it starts the process "javaw.exe" with out the *32 and does not show the program in the system tray. Do you guys know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you clarify what your task scheduler job looks like?

Comment: I am not sure what your wanted clarified? It is a basic task that is told to execute a batch file at 12:05 AM every day.

Comment: I'm talking about the user account the job is being run under (whether it's yours), the action details, especially the arguments and Start In folder (which you can see when editing the action).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you launch a process via Task Scheduler, it may have a different environment than when you launch the process from your desktop. To test this, you can create a task that runs `cmd` with the `/k` parameter from the Task Scheduler. When you run it, cmd will open, then you can run `set >%userprofile%\Desktop\environment1.txt`. Then, open a cmd as you normally do, and run `set >%userprofile%\Desktop\environment2.txt`. Open the two files side by side, and compare.

In this case, I suspect your PATH variables are different, which is why 32-bit java is run in one case, and 64-bit in another.

To fix this, you could explicitly specify the 64-bit javaw.exe in your batch file.

`C:\path\to\javaw.exe` instead of just `javaw`.